# adding ghci's inferred type signature causes an error

Tags: haskell, type-families

Edit: Here's a truly simple example. Motivation for this example below.

This compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family F a b

f :: a -> F a b
f = undefined

f' [a] = f a
```

And ghci reports that:

```
*Main> :t f'
f' :: [a] -> F a b
```

But if we add this type signature to the file above, it complains:

```
*Main> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:9:14:
    Couldn't match type `F a b0' with `F a b'
    NB: `F' is a type function, and may not be injective
    In the return type of a call of `f'
    In the expression: f a
    In an equation for `f'': f' [a] = f a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What gives?

---

**Motivation:**

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529262/removing-common-haskell-piping-boilerplate), I thought I'd be a smart-alec and write a little joke solution. The plan of attack is to start with type-level numbers (as usual), then write a little type-level function `Args n a c` that yields the function type that takes `n` copies of `a` and yields a `c`. Then we can write a little type class for the various `n` and be on our way. Here's what I *want* to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Z = Z
data S a = S a

type family Args n a c
type instance Args Z a c = c
type instance Args (S n) a c = a -> Args n a c

class OnAll n where
    onAll :: n -> (b -> a) -> Args n a c -> Args n b c

instance OnAll Z where
    onAll Z f c = c

instance OnAll n => OnAll (S n) where
    onAll (S n) f g b = onAll n f (g (f b))
```

I was surprised to discover that this didn't type-check!

Comment: This is certainly more effort than I devoted to simplifying that example! What GHC version are you using, before I try and dig too deeply into this?

Comment: @ehird I checked with ghc-7.2.2 and ghc-7.3.20111114.

Comment: (My suspicion, FWIW, is that this is a bug in GHC. However, I think ``NB: `Args' is a type function, and may not be injective`` might be relevant too; the bug might simply be in how `:t` displays names or the like, rather than in the type-checker itself.)

Comment: Ah, thanks; I can reproduce this on 7.0.3 too. Hmm...

Comment: @ehird I've also minimized a bit more, see the updated question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried explicitly giving `a`'s type with `ScopedTypeVariables` and `RankNTypes`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: This is even worse than you might think; from a discussion of this in an IRC channel I frequent: "Note that the `[]` is apparently superfluous. I.e., `f' :: a -> F a b; f' a = f a` has the same problem." I'll amend my answer accordingly; this is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a GHC bug, as can be demonstrated by the following, even further simplified example:

```
type family F a

f :: b -> F a
f = undefined

f' :: b -> F a
f' a = f a
```

I suggest reporting it to GHC HQ.

Comment: Nice tip. I'll do you one better still: `type family F a; x, y :: F a; x = undefined; y = x`.

Comment: Ha! You managed that 29 seconds before I edited in an even simpler example from IRC than my previous one. Well, at least we can be sure it's a bug now...

Comment: Accepting this answer; to give a quick update, this "bug" (?) was resolved in GHC by making the version without a type annotation stop compiling. =)